# Authorization_RequestDenied on setting value for user key object using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to have an extra claim say "mygroupsrmm" in my jwt token which I want to view post decoding the token.
I am trying to add custom claims to my jwt token which I will receive post authentication using Oauth2 flow. I've already modified application manifest file for registered AAD app with

> "acceptMappedClaims": true

& followed below steps:

//Step1 - Created custom policy

> New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true","ClaimsSchema":[{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute2","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/rmmgname","JwtClaimType":"mygroupsrmm"}]}
> }') -DisplayName "MyGroupsRMMExtraClaims" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

//Step2 - assigned policy to my AAD registered app

> $appID = <>
> $sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "servicePrincipalNames/any(n: n eq '$appID')"
> $policyId = <>
> Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policyId

Above both steps are successful, now I went ahead with authentication calls

//Step3 : GET /authorize API call

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=my-application-id-registered-in-AAD&
> redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access%20User.Read%20Files.Read

From this step, authorization code is received, which is passed on to the /token API call

//Step4: POST /token call

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<<my-application-id-registered-in-AAD>>
&client_secret=<<client-secret-value-here>>
&code=<<code-received-from-step3>>
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/callback
```

The above call is successfully executed & returned both access_token & id_token
But post decoding token I'm unable to view my added custom claims i.e "mygroupsrmm" (viewed decoded token through [jwt.io](https://jwt.io))

On checking my user details from Graph explorer, "extensionattribute2" is null, so for this key field tried updating the value using

//Step5: Navigate to [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) & execute the call

```
/PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
body
{
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute2": "myrmm-g2"
    }
}
```

Above call throws

> "Forbidden - 403 - 492ms. You need to consent to the permissions on
> the Modify permissions (Preview) tab"

while on viewing "Modify permissions (Preview)", all the required permissions i.e User.ManageIdentities.All, User.ReadWrite.All, User.ReadWrite, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All are already granted(Consented)

```
//response
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-23T12:08:05",
            "request-id": "06ddd00b-db0f-4a7c-ae03-471763139939",
            "client-request-id": "c07843cf-89d4-10a7-89fa-f3b71445bc1f"
        }
    }
}
```

Authorization token used for above request contains below consented permissions/scopes

```
"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite openid profile User.ManageIdentities.All User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All email"
```

Since above request is failed, I've tried modifying another user object key value i.e jobTitle to check user update response

```
/PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
{ "jobTitle" : "sr.mts"}
```

This call too throws **403** error with code **Authorization_RequestDenied**

I would like to know what specific permission is required to set values for above keys i.e jobTitle or extensionAttribute2 to view the custom claim key-value in decoded jwt token.
Any sort of assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you an administrator?

Comment: No, I'm not an administrator, but my admin has given consent for all the required permissions i.e, User.ManageIdentities.All, User.ReadWrite.All, User.ReadWrite, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All

Comment: You must be an administrator to modify this attribute. I have tested it just now.

Comment: Alright let me ask the admin to modify this attribute and check again

Comment: Okay, try to grant your user the global administrator role.

Comment: Hi, is there an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be an administrator to modify this attribute. I have tested it just now.

[image]

**Update :** Post assigning **Directory writer** role to the AAD user, above issue is fixed. [See here for success calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CddwD.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Carl, thankyou for your response, can you check once with this {"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {"extensionAttribute2": "myrmm-g2"}}

Comment: @AmritPalSingh  I tried it with `{"onPremisesExtensionAttributes":{"extensionAttribute2":"myrmm-g2"}}` as the request body, and it returned 400 to me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rfBh.png.  I'm not sure if you can change the `onPremisesExtensionAttributes` attribute because I don't see it in the request body of the api document of the [`Update user`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body).

Comment: @AmritPalSingh  Did you try to grant the user the administrator role and then test it? How is the result?

Comment: I've tried same request, but it returned 405 to me (https://imgur.com/a/n6yJBSC)

Comment: @AmritPalSingh  This is very strange, I did not encounter this error, is your account a work or school account? Try using other api tools such as postman.

Comment: I tried above request with my personal account, also you can check here response 405 when tried in postman (https://imgur.com/a/B82hKaX)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229141/discussion-between-amrit-pal-singh-and-carl-zhao).